# PHP MySQL array inside fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form where a user can input a ShopID, multiselect from a list of cars, and a price for the group. The list of cars inserts into the database such as "audi, saab, volvo".

I am now trying to display a table that shows all the ShopID, selected cars and group price. Ideally, this is what the table would look like:

```
Shop ID    Cars    Price
          audi
1         saab     100
          volvo
--------------------------- (this is a table border)
          saab
2         bmw      200
          ford
          honda
```

This table shows the shop ID that is associated with all cars and the group price (rather than a shopID and a price for each car).

Right now, however, I am getting all the cars to only show on one line such as:

```
Shop ID         Cars            Price
1         audi, saab, volvo     100
```

Does anybody know how I can loop through the array in "Cars" and show each one on it's own line...while keeping the "Shop ID" and "Price" only showing once and all this information in one ?
Currently, my code for creating this table is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>ShopID</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
<?php   
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
          $output = '<tr>';
                  $output .= '<td>'.$row['shopID'].'</td>';
                  $output .= '<td>'.$row['cars'].'</td>';
                  $output .= '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
                  $output .= '</tr>';

                  echo $output;
}
?>
</table>
```

Thanks!

***EDIT***
I did try to use explode(), but I ran into the same problem where I didn't know how to get them onto their own line!

Comment: Then just store price individually for each car. It would be soooo much easier...

Comment: try with explode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on your cars

```
$cars = str_replace(",", "<br/>", $row['cars']);
$output .= '<td>'.$cars.'</td>';
```

Comment: This worked out well...I should have thought of this idea. I was trying to think too complex, ha! Thanks. I will accept answer in a couple minutes when SO allows it

Answer (score 2):

using explode()

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $output = '<tr>';
              $output .= '<td>'.$row['shopID'].'</td>';
              $car = explode(",",$row['cars']);
              $output .= '<td>';
              foreach($car as $c)
              {
              $output .= $c."</br>";
              }
              $output .='</td>';
              $output .= '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
              $output .= '</tr>';
              echo $output;
 }
```

using str_replace()

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $output = '<tr>';
              $output .= '<td>'.$row['shopID'].'</td>';
              $cars = str_replace(",", "<br/>", $row['cars']);
              $output .= '<td>'.$cars.'</td>';
              $output .= '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
              $output .= '</tr>';
              echo $output;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Kevin...good answer..it is nice seeing multiple ways of achieving this. I tested both answers and they both work, but I have already accepted an answer before your answer was given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to modify `$row['cars']`.

`$carsMultiLine = str_replace(", ", "<br />", $row['cars']);`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ryan27...this did work, but I used the answer from @Ian because he had posted it first.